# Using an Eclipse Project (Structure) in Android Studio without damaging the Structure

Tags: eclipse, svn, gradle, android-studio, project-structure

I am absolutely new to stackoverflow (first question :D) so I hope I'll get all the rules in my Head asap :D.

Sooo..here comes my Question:

**Is there a Possibility to work on an Eclipse Project in Android Studio, without destroying the Project structure??**

The Background behind this is the following:
A colleague and myself are working together on an Android App...he uses Eclipse and I want to use Android Studio. Thats why **I need to work with an Elipse-Project-structure in Android studio.**
In addition we are using subversion.

I have already googled but found only questions about how to import Eclipse Projects in Android Studio.

I don't really need an option to import an Android Studio Project in Eclipse, I just want to be sure, that i can work with an Eclipse Project in AS.

I Hope I gave you guys enough informations of my intentions.

-Tips for gradle concerning this matter are welcome-

(Sorry for the bad formulations and/or my english skills ^_^ )